# Creating a html table dynamically based on Yii (relations)database table?

Tags: php, html, yii, styling

I am trying to create "view" or a function that will build a HTML table by being given the columns in the table and the table data itself. This will be a page called by the renderPartial method in Yii.
I imagined doing it something like this (will demonstrate using pseudo-code):

```
    void view(array $cols, array $tabledata) 
    {
    //$tabledata will be an array of CActiveRecord objects. $cols is an array of strings from getColumnNames().
    <table><thead><tr>
    foreach($cols as $col)
    {
        <th>$col</th>
    }
    </tr></thead><tbody>
    foreach($tabledata as $data)
    {
        <tr>
        foreach($cols as $col)
        {
            <td>$data->$col</td>
        }
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody></table>
    }
```

However the issue I am running into is I cannot get an the columns for a relation. I found http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbTableSchema but that seems to only give you the column names for a specific table. I need a way to get all the columns used when a relation will be used to generate the HTML table. Alternatively if someone has a better way of doing this let me know. Thanks!

Edit: As a note, the reason I am not using CGridView including the one I listed below, is that I don't want to have to know what the columns are or the data. I want to be able to build the table using just code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else who is looking to learn how to do this here is sort of how I came up with a solution:

```
--Model--
//Attributes:
$name;
$age;
$data;

--Controller--
//Controller stuff
public function actionShow()
{
  $this->render('show',array('model'=>loadModel(1)));
}

--view--
//traditonal way
echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('name');
echo CHtml::encode($model->name);
echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('age');
echo CHtml::encode($model->age);
echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('data');
echo CHtml::encode($model->data);

//one function way
foreach ($model->attributes as $col=>$val)
{
  CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel($col);
  CHtml::encode($val);
}
```

That was what I was looking for, in case someone else wanted to try.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to create a function like that. [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) is what you are looking for. It renders the data as an html table.Below is a sample code.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => new CArrayDataProvider($tabledata),
        'columns' => array(
         //specify the colums you wanted here
        ),
    ));
?>
```

Comment: I should have specified that there are specific functions that I need to use that cannot be used in conjunction with CGridView.

Comment: You mean function inside the table generation logic? In that case you can easily extend CGridView and override the renderTableRow(),renderTableHeader() etc etc

Comment: And if you want related columns, you can call `CActiveRecord`'s `getRelated()` function

Comment: The specific issue is that I need to be able to use filter and sort on a large number of columns that are derived via relations. CGridView does not offer an easy way of doing so.

Comment: The issue is that I have more than just one or two columns that need to be sorted AND filtered. There would be a lot of additions required to the model to make it sort and filter using the built-in methods. I have opted to use a jquery plugin for that. I opted not to use CGridView since I would use an external plugin.